# How to show data content from single page which is from custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, single

I have created custom post type with name Projects. and also created single-projects.php. the code is here

```
<?php
                  $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'projects',
                    'posts_per_page' => '1',
                    'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID )
                             );
                     // the query
                    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

                    // The Loop
                    if ( $query->have_posts() )  ?>

                 <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post() ; ?>

                                    <!-- start project content -->
                                    <div class="project-content">

                                        <h2>Your Project Description</h2>

                                      <?php the_content(); ?> 

                           </div>

                     <?php  endwhile;  ?>
```

Now i want to show the content for single page. But the content is not coming from related page. The content is coming from latest project content which i create. How can i solve the problem? thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

single-projects.php - should contain the following code:

```
<?php
get_header();
if (have_posts()) :
   while (have_posts()) :
      the_post();
         the_content();
   endwhile;
endif;
get_sidebar();
get_footer(); 
?>
```

To display tekschey record does not necessarily use `$query = new WP_Query ($ args);`